# how do I filter my data from one column based on another?

Tags: mysql, syntax

I need to filter the `sum(f.film_id)` as films made to be based on the actor who made them or the `actor_id`. however I'm having a hard time figuring out the syntax for said query.

```
select concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) as full_name, f.release_year, sum(f.film_id) as films_made
    from actor a
        join film_actor fa
        on a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
        join film f 
        on fa.film_id = f.film_id
        group by concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name)
        order by first_name;
```

This is my query so far.

This is the desired outcome:

[image: Desired output]

This is what I am currently getting:

[image: Current output]

Comment: This seems odd, why would an *arbitrary* sum of the `film_id` directly correlate to `actor_id` who made that film?...wouldn't the sum of `film_id` be somewhat random?

Comment: agreed however i need it to basically tell me how many films the actor has produced which I have assumed the actor id (telling me which actor it is) will correspond to a specific film or film id, but I want it to count the number of films that pop up corresponding to any actors. for example looking at the actor_film table it shows that actor_id 15 corresponds to five different films. i hope I am making sense.

Comment: please add a [mre] with all incl. results

Comment: @nbk im sorry i don't understand what you are asking

Comment: a typo a [mre] is needed

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood your initial question. So your issue right now is the count of the `films_made` column is wrong currently?

Answer (score 1):

As J.D. has alluded, the `films_made` column should be using `COUNT()` rather than `SUM()`. If the query is to show the number of movies released per actor per year, then you’ll want to add `release_year` into the `GROUP_BY`. Otherwise, if you are looking for one row per actor, you may want to use `MIN()` or `MAX()` with the `release_year` to show when they appeared in their first or most recent movie.

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) as full_name,
       MAX(f.release_year) as recent_year,
       COUNT(f.film_id) as films_made
  FROM actor a INNER JOIN film_actor fa ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
               INNER JOIN film f ON fa.film_id = f.film_id
 GROUP BY full_name
 ORDER BY full_name;
```

**Notes:**

- MySQL will allow you to use concatenated columns in a `GROUP BY`
- As the first column in `full_name` is `first_name`, you can also `ORDER BY` the `full_name` value. This makes the query a little more readable if you have to come back to it in the future.